# Index match returning N/A, value present

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I'm trying to return a value from a table containing new URLs, given an old URL. The URLs are stored in two separate tables.

I'm trying to use the index match function using column names which I thought should have worked but I'm unable to return a value. I keep getting N/A. I know for a fact the lookup value is present and I don't believe there to be any formatting issues. Any thoughts on this?

[image: The top table is where I want to insert information from... The values are blanked out so I can keep my job...]

Please let me know if there are any issues with the actual values being blanked out and I'll make a dummy table with desserts or something...

Edit: Also, in the formula the value "E19" was originally the entire column for in the table. That didn't work either so I was playing around with it.

Edit 2: Here's the text of the formula

Edit 3: Found the issue. The problem was that there was an extra space in the columns being searched. I pasted those columns from an XML document which had the extra spaces for some reason.

=INDEX(Table14[new url],MATCH([@url],Table14[url],0))

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through using "Evaluate Formula"?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means exactly. I'm going to do a quick google search but do you mind explaining?

Comment: Please include the formula in the text of your question, instead of showing it in a picture.

Comment: @DougGlancy added

Comment: It's on the Formulas tab. It allows you to evaluate each part of the formula separately to see which part of it raises the error

Comment: I'll look into it and see if I can't figure out what's going on... I tried the formula using dummy data but doing the same thing conceptually and it worked just fine. Not sure what to make of this...

Comment: It looks fine. If it works with dummy data, I think there must be a difference between your two URLs. Have you pasted the same URL in both columns to test?

Comment: Yes I tried that, and using your suggestion of the eval formula functionality I was able to see that it's the match causing the problem. I'll continue to work on it.

Comment: So looking at the match formula evaluation I found that it's able to resolve each argument correctly, but it still returns #n/a.. Not sure what could be the issue here.

Comment: That probably means it wasn't able to find a match. If it looks like it should be able to, there might be some whitespace somewhere messing up the comparison.